# Update users table when running create action of different model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Just to show you how I got to this point:

Every **user has many profiles**. Every profile has type recognized by single table inheritance(amateur, professional, and some other). I need to store **current_profile** somewhere and somehow.

**Professionals Controller**

```
class ProfessionalsController < ApplicationController
def create
  @professional = Professional.new(professional_params)
  @user = current_user
  @professional.user_id = current_user.id
  @update_current_profile = User.update(@user, {:current_profile => @professional.id})
  if @professional.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end

private

  def professional_params
    params.require(:professional).permit(:id, :username, :user_id)
  end

end
```

This is meant to update current_profile of user to the newly created professional profile and do some staff then.

When the profile is created current_profile is set(updated) to NULL. If I change  :

```
@update_current_profile = User.update(@user, {:current_profile => @professional.id})
```

to something different, for example:

```
@update_current_profile = User.update(@user, {:current_profile => @professional.user_id})
```

or

```
@update_current_profile = User.update(@user, {:current_profile => 3})
```

it stores data in User.current_profile perfectly.

I was trying @professional without an .id too. Why is this doing so?

Another question is. Is this the best way to store current_profile of user? Would you recommend me any better/safer/more efficient solution?

Thanks all of you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@professional` is a new, unsaved record and therefore does not have an `id` yet. Can only update the `current_profile` once the `@professional` record was saved.

Just reorder the lines a bit and it should work:

```
def create
  @professional = Professional.new(professional_params)
  @user = current_user
  @professional.user_id = current_user.id
  if @professional.save
    @update_current_profile = User.update(@user, {:current_profile => @professional.id})
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```

Just another tip: You use many instance variables (the one with the `@`) in this method. I do not know enough about your code, but I would suggest to look if some of them can be replaced with local variables. Rule of thumb: Only use instance variables in controllers when you want to share that variable with another method or the view.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I was trying this before and always got the "Missing template" error. I thought it is because of missing users/edit(update) template. And of course it was caused by not not giving the behavior after saving those things :D :D Thanks for pointing me to the solution. It was the first time I was doing something like this. Btw, do you think this kind of storing current_user is a good thing? Would you try it in a different way?